# Evaluating a triple integral using rectangular, cylindrical, and spherical.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The question:

Let $D$ be the solid region in the first octant inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and below the upper nappe of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$. Set up but do not evaluate $\iiint_D\, x+yz^2\, dV$.

a.) In rectangular coordinates

b.) In cylindrical coordinates

c.) In spherical coordinates

This gave me trouble earlier and my solutions for them gave me different final answers for each one. I will be updating this as I work through it again with my attempts.

Ill start with cylindrical (being what I think is the easiest):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\,\int_0^2\, \int_0^r\, (r^2cos\theta +r^2sin\theta\,z^2)\, dz\, dr\, d\theta$$

Here is my attempt in rectangular:

$$\int_0^{2}\,\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\, \int_0^\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\, (x+yz^2)\, dz\, dy\, dx$$

These seem to be holding true and giving the same answer. Now with spherical I am confused about the bounds of rho.

Comment: Where were you exactly stuck at?

Comment: Rectangular and spherical coordinates. Specifically the bounds for rho in spherical is confusing me. I believe my answer may be correct with cylindrical but I am not positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did in rectangular and polar looks fine.

In spherical coordinates: the cone has equation $\phi=\pi/4$ and the cylinder has equation $\rho=2/\sin\phi$. It follows that

$$
D=\{(\rho, \theta,\phi)\;|\; 0\le \rho \le 2/\sin\phi , \pi/4 \le \phi \le \pi/2, 0\le \theta \le \pi/2 \}.
$$